# More formulas for joint entropy and for trace form entropies

Tags: pr.probability, ergodic-theory, entropy

Linked to some applications of entropy to combinatorics I'm looking for formulas expressing the joint entropy of two r. v. as a function of the conditional entropy . For example

For BWS extensive entropy H         : $ H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y[X) $

For q-Tsallis non extensive entropy H : $ H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y|X) + (1-q)\cdot H(X) \cdot H(Y|X)$

These formula having generalisations for $n$ random variables $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$

There are many different variants of trace form non extensive entropies. To name a few:
Abe, Kaniadakis, Curado, Ubriaco, Shafee, etc....

I'm looking for smilar formulas but for other trace form entropies (different from BWS or Tsallis)

Thanks in advance for any advise or web pointers on dedicated papers

Comment: Can you give some references to where those other entropies are defined/used?

Comment: Yes, here is a good overview of generalized entropies:

[JM Amigo](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/20/11/813/pdf)

If you want to see basic on. how to use entropy functionals in combinatorics:

[David Galvin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7872.pdf)